# Why is str.match using regular expression not working in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

We are trying to extract rows whose column contains **strictly** one of the following values `[TC1, TC2, TC3]`. The trick is that some columns contain the following values also `TC12,TC13` etc. We don't want to extract them. Using `str.contains` is not option in here.

```
Col_1 Col_2 Col_3
  1    A     TC1
  2    B     TC2
  3    C     TC3
  4    D     TC12
  5    D     TC15
  6    D     TC16

Col_1 Col_2 Col_3
  1    A     TC1
  2    B     TC2
  3    C     TC3
```

We used the following commands:

```
df1 = df.loc[df1['Col_3'].str.match("TC\d{1}")]
df1 = df.loc[df1['Col_3'].str.match("TC[1-3]{1}")]
df1 = df.loc[df1['Col_3'].str.match("TC[1,2,3]")]
```

But ***the problem is that is not working. Instead of returning the first 3 columns it is returning all of the columns***. We don't understand why it's wrong.

Comment: d{1} returns you only d, that's why it is giving you all the rows in return. add $ at the end, check my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TC\d{1}` will match every columns, you need to specify that you want to stop at the end of the line to catch only the ones with one digit at the end. You can do this with **$** char.

```
TC\d{1}$
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the terminating character "$".

It's probably best to use both the starting "^" and terminating character to be more specific.

- ^: defines the start of the match
- $: defines the end of the match

Try this:

```
df1 = df.loc[df['Col_3'].str.match(r"^TC\d{1}$")]
```

Answer (score 2):

In your regex d{1} ultimately returns you d that's why it returns all the matches. 
You need to explicitly end your string by adding $ in your regex.

```
df1 = df.loc[df1['Col_3'].str.match("TC[1-3]{1}$")]
```